# Operation on Regular expressions?

Tags: regex, intersection

How to solve intersection of two regular expressions as in below:

```
(01*10*) ∩  (10*01) = {}=φ (how  ?)
(0*1*1)* ∩ (1*0*0)* = {ε}
```

And Union of two RE as in :

```
(a*b)*U(ba*)* = (a+b)* (how ?)
```

Also Please explain a general method to solve operations on Regular expressions. (Any links will be helpful)

Thanks.

Comment: From `[regex]` tag description: __Please include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using, together with this tag.__

Comment: @LevLevitsky - This question seems mostly implementation-independent. Perhaps it's more appropriate for cs.stackexchange.com though.

Comment: @acheong87 The question may seem implementation-independent, but the answers may not. Your answer won't work in all languages, for example.

Comment: @LevLevitsky - The user's _language_ (set notation) suggested he was interested in a theoretical answer. Which is why I said the question might be more appropriate for cs. I really don't think it's necessary for the user to specify a language in this case, though. That's like refusing to answer a question because a word in the title was spelled wrong. We know what he meant. If it's so ambiguous that we must make it clear, then fine: **Warning: Not all implementations support lookaround assertions and/or alternation.**

Comment: @acheong87 The part in bold is pretty much what I meant :)

Comment: There are no such operators on regular expressions, what if you just explained what you really wanted to do? It looks like you want to shoehorn a square peg in a round hole here.

Comment: @fge - I hate to be the only one defending OP, and worse, I'm now in a biased position as I've offered an answer, but: I think OP's question is based on the fact that there _are_ no such (obvious) operators, as you say. I believe he's asking for a substitution: a general method for decomposing the two (important) operators into regular expressions' constructs, perhaps to create a generic mechanism for combining search sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For intersection, there's lookaheads:

```
(?=01*10*)(?=10*01)
```

For union, there's alternation:

```
(a*b)*|(ba*)*
```

I don't have a general link for you, but other operations can be decomposed to those plus negative lookaheads.

Comment: Lookaheads don't provide a guarantee both branches will be of the same length.

Comment: `(?=a)(?=aa)` will match `aa`, `a ∩ aa` will not.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Hm, good point. But, maybe `a ∩ aa` _should_ match `aa`? If each atom is meant to be a regex, then both atoms do match, don't they? If we are only meaning to match `a` not followed by another `a`, then shouldn't the expression be `a[^a] ∩ aa`? Or, if we wish to match the complete string, then say, `^a$ ∩ ^aa$`. In that interpretation, lookaheads would be sufficient. But I don't know what the correct interpretation is.

Comment: `a ∩ aa` should match nothing at all, since nothing is both `a` and `aa`.

Comment: Lookaheads are not sufficient if you can't use string boundary assertions (or, more generally, assertions that match at a unique place.

Comment: @JanDvorak - I understand your argument (I studied set theory, if that gives any credence), but I'm not sure you see mine, yet. In OP's question, it's apparent each of the sides are regular expressions themselves. That means `a ∩ aa` may not mean what it seems to mean, but rather, "The intersection of the regular expression, `a`, and the regular expression, `aa`." You see, in that case, the result is not necessarily an empty set.

Comment: If you allow lookahead as well as concatenation, you have a problem. You can't reliably concatenate two intersections. You can create an intersection of two regexes with a lookahead but you can't concatenate the intersection with anything.

Comment: @JanDvorak - One more try! I mean not an intersection of the regular expression _strings_ themselves, but intersection of the _result sets of_ the two regular expressions. If you look at OP's examples, that's what he is indicating, after all. So, `a` would match `aa`, and `aa` would match `aa`, so the intersection would be `aa`.